# Interrupting an infinite loop in Golang with signals

Tags: loops, for-loop, go, signals, sigint

I'm trying to make a program that uses signals to interrupt an infinite counter loop. I've managed to interrupt the program with SIGINT (ctrl + C), but I'm unable to interrupt it otherwise. I'm wondering if I can make other ways of interrupting the loop, for example by pressing the Q key while it is running in the terminal.

I've made two Go-files, the first one containing the actual infinite loop:

```
package infinite

import "fmt"
import "time"

func Infinite01 (msg string) {
for i := 0; ; i++ {
    fmt.Println(msg, i)
    time.Sleep(time.Second)
    }
}
```

And then the file to catch the SIGINT signal and interrupt the loop:

```
package main

import (
"./infinite"
"os/signal"
"os"
"fmt"
)

func main() {
sigs := make(chan os.Signal, 1)
signal.Notify(sigs, os.Interrupt)
go func() {
    <-sigs
    fmt.Printf("You pressed ctrl + C. User interrupted infinite loop.")
    os.Exit(0)
}()
Loop()
}

func Loop() {
infinite.Infinite01("Look, I can count forever:")
}
```

Comment: What you want to acheive is simply 1) capture a key stroke in terminal 2) when a specified key stroke is captured, exit the program 3) the whole process does not block the program so it can run other codes (like an infinite loop). The thrid part is auctually done with the goroutine, so only two left. And I believe searching both of them on Google will yield helpful results.

Comment: @leafbebop who said the OP wanted user input, that would the obvious solution.

Comment: @Remario What would you say the OP want instead?

Comment: As far as I can tell "pressing the Q key" is not sending a signal nor anything else than a key stroke.

Comment: I understand I might have phrased myself badly here. What I want to do is to create an interruption signal in addition to Ctrl + C that can be used for the same thing (interrupting a running infinite loop process). Is that possible? If so, how would I do it? Thanks for the quick responses!

Comment: @Kstulen would you show some code of how c++ do it so we can understand what you mean better?

Comment: I might have talked past myself here actually. Are there any other signals that could be used to interrupt/terminate an infinite loop process? Would it work if I added os.Kill? I’m sorry, I can’t provide any c++ code, I’m totally new to this...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Then I would stick to my first comment. I would explain a little more.

You don't need a signal to have your program terminate - you have control over it. Call `os.Exit` at any time would exit the program, and return from `main()` has the same effect.

The problem is, instead, that when to trigger these "exits". Or, in your example, how to trigger the exit when the `key Q` is pressed.

To solve the problem, you need to break it down into parts. As I said in the comments, the part 1 is capturing the key stroke. It is not as simple as an `fmt.Scan`, as it would require the user press an enter after it. It requires some os specific code to do so, but hopefully a lib can save you all the trouble, like [termbox-go](https://github.com/nsf/termbox-go).

The part 2 is tightly associated with part 1. That is to specify the event, the key stroke. In your example, to know the key pressed is Q, and then call `os.Exit`. Usually a lib can handle that pretty easily, sometimes one can hardly notice there is a part. But if you want some more complicated key stokes, like `ctrl-alt-backspace`, or even `a-s-d-f` (at the same time), this will require some codes.

The 3rd part is about not blocking the program. In Go, it can easily be acheived by using a seperate goroutine to check an event loop, or use the good-old callback way. It is up to library you pick.

A little more about signal and the `ctrl-c` case. It is common practice that `ctrl-c` is bound to send a sigint to the program, in most situations. And if not modified, a sigint terminates a program. However, a program can modify the behavior of dealing with sigint, like your orignal code does (adds a message to print). When pressing other keys, it is unlikely the os would bind it to another signal, so you can not deal with it.

Of corse another solution would be bind a key compostion (multiple key strokes) to sending a sigint to the program, but as long as the program is the program receiving the key stroke itself, that is a redunctant.

Note: Because of the choice of libs can be varied, the codes are very much differed, so I don't think I can (or should) provide an example.

Comment: Thanks for a great reply! This leaves me with some options. I will check them out!